# Create Magic Square Function and write to file

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a constructor to create a MagicSqaure

```java
private int[][] matrix;
private boolean isSquare;

public MagicSquare (String filename, int n) throws IOException
    {
        if (n % 2 != 1)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Dimensions must be odd");
        }
        else
        {
            int row = n-1;
            int col = n/2;
            this.matrix[row][col] = 1;

            for (int i = 2; i <= n*n; i++) {
                if (this.matrix[(row + 1) % n][(col + 1) % n] == 0) {
                    row = (row + 1) % n;
                    col = (col + 1) % n;
                }
                else {
                    row = (row - 1 + n) % n;

                }
                this.matrix[row][col] = i;
            }
        }

        File file = new File(filename);
        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        //Need to write items to file here
        outFile.close();
    }
```

I'm a little confused in two spots on this assignment

1. I am not exactly sure how to take this 2-d Array and convert it into a text file like so

```
3 //this first line is the dimension(s) of the magic square
123
456
789
```

2. When I try to run the code without the file creation and simply look to generate a magicSquare from my driver class

```java
public class MagicSquareDriver {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("-create"))
        {
            MagicSquare square = new MagicSquare(args[1], Integer.parseInt(args[2]));

            System.out.println(square.toString());
        }

        else if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("-check"))
        {
            MagicSquare square = new MagicSquare(args[1]);

            System.out.println(square.toString());
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

    }
}
```

I end up with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MagicSquare.<init>(MagicSquare.java:53)
    at MagicSquareDriver.main(MagicSquareDriver.java:6)
```

Comment: Which line is `MagicSquare.java:53`? line 53 of that class? What is null on that line?

Comment: I don't see where you allocate `matrix`. As in: `matrix = new int[n][n];`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp that was the issue for the nullPointerException I forgot to instantiate the matrix

Comment: @Arvind in a general sense yes but the question really is two parts so not sure that it should be flagged for closing as a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly understand how you want to write the array to the file, but if I wanted to traverse the array row after row looking at all the columns, I could do this:

```
outFile.println(dimension)

for (int i = 0; i < totalRows; i++) {
  for (int j = 0, j< totalColumns, j++) {
     int value = this.matrix[i][j];
        boolean newLine = ???
        if (newLine) {
           outFile.println(value) //For printing on a new line
        } else {
           outFile.print(value)   //For printing on the same line
        }
  }
}
```

You need to decide with newLine when to move to the next line or when to write on the same line, I don't exactly understand when do you write a new line but you can see the idea.

Comment: So if the square is give a length of 5 by 5 by the user

the first line in the document would need to be 5
the next 5 lines of the document would need to be 5 numbers each to make 5 rows and 5 columns of the magic square

Comment: then totalRows and totalColumns are 5

Comment: yup I hadn't seen your edit yet, what is the function of this boolean NewLine though

Comment: you need to decide yourself when it's time to move to a new line, I just didn't know it myself so replace ?? with your condition, for example when j == totalColumns-1 then newLine = true

Comment: yup I figured it out greatly appreaciated